# Getting junk while accessing federationMetadata.xml on Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, adfs, single-sign-on, saml

I have setup ADFS on windows server 2012R2 using self signed certificate.
ADFS has been installed successfully.
But when I try to access the federationMetadata.xml using 
https:///FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml;
I get junk output in IE.

[federationMetadata.xml output in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGZ6c.png)
[image: federationMetadata.xml output in IE]

I have not configured CA on my server.
Please guide me on what can be the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean the following format URL?

https://<server-name>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Comment: Well, I don't think the screenshot necessarily shows "junk" ;-) To me it just seems as if the content is not correctly rendered as XML.

Comment: @ComponentSpace Using the right URL.

Comment: @khlr Any suggestion to render it as XML. I want to use this file with shibboleth.

Comment: Did you try another browser than IE?

Comment: Have you tried Compatibility View.

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility view settings in IE solved the issue for me.